# 'User' object has no attribute 'set_password' Django error

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Делаю сайт с регистрацией пользователей на Django с базой данных SQLite. Но так же при запуске выдаёт ошибку "'User' object has no attribute 'set_password'".

Мой models:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

Мой forms:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from .models import *


class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Логин', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form- 
input'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 
'form-input'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Повтор пароля', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs= 
{'class': 'form-input'}))

   class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')
    widgets = {
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-input"}),
        'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-input"}),
        'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-input"}),
    }
```

Мой views:

```
from main.forms import RegisterUserForm

class RegisterUser(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    template_name = 'main/reg.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
```

Comment: Очевидно, в вашей модели User и в самом деле нету никакого set_password. Если вы хотите заменить стандартную модель, читайте в документации как это делать правильно https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Answer (score 1):

Для расширения модели пользователя в вашем случает лучше использовать класс `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser`. Подробнее https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/. Вы не отнаследовали и не определили необходимые для работы приложения аутенфикации поля, отсюда и получается такая ошибка.